# Can this reference in run() refer to Thread object when implementing Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, self-destruction

Sorry if the question is unclear

I am making a simple multithread program that has a linked list to store all thread created except the main thread. Then I want to send some signal to terminate the main thread but only when all other threads have closed and I intend to do this by making that when the thread close, it will remove itself from linked list then the main thread will check if that list size == null or not

here is my code

```
public class MainProgram {
    //some global static variable
    static List<Thread> threadList = new LinkedList<Thread>();
    public void main() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        while(true){
            if(Shutdown_Handler.shutdown==true){
                //wait for all other thread close/terminate
                return
            }
            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientThread x = new ClientThread(s);
            Thread y = new Thread(x);
            threadList.add(y);
            y.start();

        }
    }
}
```

when Shutdown_Handler.shutdown==true the main will check the threadList if it is `null`. The problem is I don't know how to make the thread remove itself from the list. As what I have searched, for normal object, I can create method like this

```
public class someObject {
    public static void delete(){
        if(list.size = null) return;
        list.remove(this);
    }
}
```

However, in case of thread, the Class implement `Runnable` so `this` reference is to the object but not the thread stored in the list

Comment: If I understood correctly then you can use ExecutorService with Futures which are available in Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: If you want to manipulate list in multiple threads, you should make it thread-safe, using Collections.synchronizedList(..) or something.

Comment: You can't reference *this* in static method. If you want to get current thread in Runnable class, use Thread.currentThread().

Comment: If you want to wait till a thread is running, then you can simply do t.join() in thread whose execution you want to pause. [read it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

Comment: Why? The program won't exit until all the non-daemon threads have exited. You don't need any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a `HashMap` instead of a `List`. The keys can be the Thread Name (e.g. `Thread.getName()`) and the values will be the Threads.

```
Map<String, Thread> threadMap = new HashMap<String, Thread>();
```

You should also create this Map as a synchronizedMap (using `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)`)

```
Map<String, Thread> synchronizedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(threadMap);
```

Now, whenever you construct a Thread, you pass this HashMap into its constructor and the Thread can hold a reference to it. Therefore, when the Thread is about to terminate it can remove itself from the `HashMap` by using its own Thread name as the key to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ClientThread is a Runnable, the basic code is:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
        MainProgram.threadList.remove(Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```

However this has a couple of problems:

1. There are going to be multiple threads performing operations on a list without proper synchronization.  That is incorrect, and you are liable to get intermittent failures if you do this.
2. Unless `run()` removes the thread from the list in a `finally` block, a thread that terminates abnormally is liable to not get removed.
3. It is bad design to use a global static.  And worse design to expose it as a bare (non-private) variable.
4. A `HashSet<Thread>` would be more efficient if the number of threads is liable to be large.